# How to get php file based on URL in WordPress

Tags: php, theme-development, customization

I am trying to edit the home page for the wordpress site but I am not able to find the PHP file. The file should be under the theme file and I have checked almost all the file(which is not the correct way) but was not able to find it. Looking for some way through which I can get the exact file name via URL as in CodeIgniter we use ROUTES.PHP, if there is any way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WP determines template file by following [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). The process has quite a few steps between URL and resulting PHP file loaded, so generally one is not a reliable indication of the other.

Outside of looking through *likely* template files (good enough in a simple theme) you can try dumping this with code in `template_include` filter or using some debug plugin. For example Query Monitor shows main template file loaded.

Note that in more complicated theme (especially private ones) the *actual* PHP file might be deeply nested/included from the *initial* template file.

Comment: yes in my case the file was 3 level deep, I was looking for someway through which I can get the file but I dont think it exists. Anyways thanks for the help buddy.